# Asp.mvc - override not found behaviour for partialtemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates

The default behaviour of mvc when a partial template can not be found is to throw an error.  I am writing a custom view engine that will retrieve partials from different locations than the default.  I also want to change the behaviour such that if a partial template can not be found, then an error won't be thrown but rather a "blank" will be entered where the template was supposed to be output and then have my logger log the fact the template could not be found.  The reason for this is that we need multiple people to be able to submit "help" templates that provide some additional text, but if not found, will not throw an error because they are not important to the functioning of the screen.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry, I guess I forgot to add the second para that explained what I wanted.  Basically was asking where in the call stack I could intercept the retrieval of the partial view template since I could not find anywhere to override in a custom view engine implementation.  However, I was thinking about it too much.  I just created a custom htmlHelper that I included code for below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just created a different partial template that's called in the areas I want to return empty space if the template is not found.

```
 public static class PartialExtensions
    {
        // Methods
        public static MvcHtmlString PartialWithErrorRedirection(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName, string redirectViewName)
        {
            try
            {
                return htmlHelper.Partial(partialViewName, null, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                if (redirectViewName != null && redirectViewName.Trim().Length > 0)
                    return (htmlHelper.Partial(redirectViewName));
                else
                    return (htmlHelper.Partial("NotFound"));
            }
        }





    }
```